# Is there any way not to return arrays when specifying return fields in an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a documents like this :

```
[
    {
        "model": "iPhone",
        "brand": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "model": "Nexus 5",
        "brand": "Google"
    }
]
```

And that I make a query which only returns the `model` field in a query, like this:

```
{
    "fields": ["model"],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "brand": "apple"
        }
    }
}
```

Then each document field is returned within an array like this:

```
{ "model": ["iPhone"] }
```

instead of

```
{ "model": "iPhone" }
```

How can I avoid that and get the fields in the same format as when the `fields` query option is not defined?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the end the answer was pretty easy: you have to use the `_source` query option insteand of `fields`.

Example:

```
{
    "_source": ["model"],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "brand": "apple"
        }
    }
}
```

This way I get documents in the following format, like in the original one (without the `_source` option):

```
{ "model": "iPhone" }
```

Comment: @tyler Haha, I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: No, you deserve no upvotes, because your answer is misleading - using Fields parameter is lot more efficient than using _souce (it saves disk IOs and CPU because it doesn't have to parse the _source). I would really like to know how to return document fields using Fields definition in the same format they were supplied when indexed. It can save me a whole iteration (that can be over a lot of documents) just to remove those arrays...

Comment: @WaxCage To clafiry , when you say "save IOs/Cpu" do you are referring in the cluster or in your server to parse the data, so if we avoid the source, the ES server will save IO/CPUs or are we talking about or server side?

Comment: @jamesjara In the cluster of ES server. When indexing documents, ES saves source document and then indexes all fields mentioned by mapping. When you use fields, it can return data directly from those indicies. If you use "_source" parameter, it will have to parse all sources afterwards "on the fly" each time. If it is limited number of documents (eg 10) it merely does not matter, but if response is like 10k to 100k documents (tv broadcasts for my current example) it makes a noticeable difference. It depends on use case.

Comment: On the other hand, I haven't found any better solution to this, than using "_source" parameter! So if you need it and your desired document set is not too large (10 - 100) it may not cause any problems. I just wanted to notify about potential drawbacks of this solution. I think that it should be mentioned, so that everyone don't use "_source" as a better "fields" from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and indeed (as Wax Cage said) I thought that `_source` would bring some performances problems. I think using both `fields` and `_source` solves the problem:

```
const fields = ['model']

{
  fields: fields,
  _source: fields
  query: {
    term: {
      brand: 'apple'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't that just suffer drawbacks of both solutions? Your response is larger, because you have both fields and source in response. And the afterwards parsing of all relevant document sources happens anyway...